# NSArrayController + Core Data + Bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, binding, nsarraycontroller

I have one window containing an NSTableView listing a bunch of managed objects. I can right click a selection of those objects, and bring up an edit window to edit the properties of those objects (in theory).

Here's my code to bring up the window:

```
EditObjController *editObjController = [[EditObjController alloc] init];

// This line has to be first or the properties of editObjController are all nil.
[[editObjController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]; 
[editobjController.arrayController setManagedObjectContext:[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext]];

NSArray *selection = [_objects objectsAtIndexes: [_objectsTableView selectedRowIndexes]];
[editObjController.arrayController setContent: selection];
```

My nib for the editing window has an NSArrayController in it. I have various textfields on the window, all of which are bound to the NSArrayController, controller key 'selection', with model key path=nameoffield.

The array controller is a valid object. No errors are reported.

All that comes up when the window appears is 'No selection' in all the textfields. What am I missing? I've googled extensively and I can't find a decent tutorial that explains how to actually edit records using Core Data and Bindings.

Comment: Markdown tip: \`\` is for inline code formatting. For code blocks, you need to use four spaces or a tab at the start of every line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NSTableView and Edit Window should share the same array controller.

Comment: And once you do that, there is no reason to ask the view what is selected in it. The array controller already knows what is selected, and if you want to share in that knowledge, bind the array controller's `selectedObjectIndexes` property to a property of your own, holding a pointer to an NSIndexSet.